# Rails: show in view the combination of two queries sorted by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, the Activity and Comment models. I want to display every comment and activity sorted by the date, like:

Activities = get all activities
Comments = get all commments

@combine and sort by date, and display them to the view.

Is this even possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, assuming that `Activity` has many `Comment` you could do something like this:

Controller:

```rb
class ActivitiesController <...
  def index
    @activities = Activity.includes(:comments).order(:activity_date_column)
  end
end
```

Index view:

```rb
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
 <h1><%= activity.name %></h1>
 <% activity.comments.order(:commet_date_column) do |comment| %>
   <p><%= comment.body %></p>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```